# I can't write stuff to my self-made txtfile

Tags: java, text, bufferedwriter

I am having my first go at trying to write my own txt to a a file ,in a specific directory.
The test.mod file is correctly placed ,but when I open up the file it is empty and contains no text.
What am I missing here?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pad = "C:\\Users\\Bernard\\Documents\\Paradox Interactive";
    File bestand = new File(pad + "\\test.mod");
    try {
        BufferedWriter pen = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bestand));
        pen.write("line1");
        pen.write("line2");

    }catch(IOException e){            
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: a close statement - `pen.close();`

Comment: Thanks,that solved it.But Netbeans acts all funny saying I should convert to try-with-resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you write to a `BufferedWriter` you are (potentially) writing to an in-memory buffer, and you must `flush()` your writes to make sure they reach the disk. `close()` would also implicitly call `flush()` on any reasonable implementation, but it isn't considered a good practice to rely on it:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String pad = "C:\\Users\\Bernard\\Documents\\Paradox Interactive";
    File bestand = new File(pad + "\\test.mod");
    BufferedWriter pen = null;
    try {
        pen = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(bestand));
        pen.write("line1");
        pen.write("line2");
        pen.flush();
    }catch(IOException e){
        // Probably should have some treatment here too
    }
    finally {
        if (pen != null) {
            pen.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it normal that I would still need to add an IOException to the close-statement?

Comment: Yes. `close()` throws an `IOException`, so you'd either have to catch it, or allow `main` to throw it upwards (i.e., crash the program)